# unity android gradle build failed

Tags: android, unity3d, gradle, build

При попытке скомпилить игру в apk юнити выдает ошибку `gradle build failed`. Пытался удалить папку .gradle, не сработало. Установил новую версию едитора (2020.3.25f1), тоже без результатов. Вот что выдает консоль (дал ссылкой так как сайт не дает больше 30к символов вставить)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G8P_19HXoXDIt_jzLN3Rqb1k7C-DXeXIYnOICO6Z124/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted такая же проблема, попробуй

Comment: @lezhni там вроде говорят про поврежденный sdk, а не про gradle. я попробовал удалить API 31, но это не сработало

Comment: Ошибка точно такая же: `Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.`. Это не самого Gradle проблема, он всего лишь сборщик

Comment: ой, а я и не читал даже) спасибо, помогло